# Eclipse: Garbage Collector Button

Tags: eclipse, garbage-collection

What happens when I press the "Run Garbage Collector" button in Eclipse? Does it just call System.gc()?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Yes, it is strictly a call to the JVM, not to an internal Eclipse function (see [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools.gef/msg18687.html)).

Don't forget the **[Memory Analyzer](http://dev.eclipse.org/blogs/memoryanalyzer/2008/05/08/the-power-of-aggregation-making-sense-of-the-objects-in-a-heap-dump/)** to also check paths to garbage collection roots (in a Head Dump) if you suspect some memory leaking in your Eclipse session.

Note: that button  is only available if you select the "Show Heap status" in the General section of the Eclipse preferences:

[image]

Comment: It took me a few minutes to figure out what to do for rajasti277's tip.  Click the "General" item in the left panel.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped :)

Comment: A popular interview question is whether Garbage Collection can be enforced, and the short answer is, "no," as System.gc() merely provides a "hint" to the JVM that garbage collection should be run - i.e. it's not guarateed. Now, two questions arise: (1) What exactly does a "hint" mean in this context and (2) Does the button in Eclipse do more than simply provide a "hint?" It appears so, as the used heap memory immediately immediately decreases upon pressing it.

Answer (score 21):

Yes, the `System.gc()` is called!

Very useful in the **Eclipse –>Preferences–>General-> Show heap status**

[image]

then you can see in the lower right corner the "trash can" to run  the Garbage Collector. =)

Comment: Thank you for posting the steps!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, `System.gc()` is called when the "Run Garbage Collector" button is pressed.

Answer (score 2):

**Garbage Collection** is the process of reclaiming the runtime unused memory by destroying the unused objects. Java Garbage Collection is the process by which Java programs perform automatic memory management. Java programs compile into bytecode that can be run on a **Java Virtual Machine** (JVM).

*To enable Eclipse garbage collector button & see the status of the memory, to the following steps:*

[image]

1. *Click on Windows Drop-Down Menu.*
2. *Select Preferences*.
3. *Tick/Enable **Show Heap Status***

[image]

4. *Click Apply & Close*

Now the *GC button* & *Memory Status* is visible & you can use it to reclaim the memory which is no longer being used by a Java application and to recycle this memory for other uses.