# Is there a JVM lacking garbage collector?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

There was a comment in the question [calling-system-gc-explicitly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784987/calling-system-gc-explicitly/4785123#4785123) stating that "*You can not "force" a generic JVM to do garbage collection because a garbage collector is not actually required by the JVM spec.*". My question is if there's such a JVM (and how and where does it get used, if so).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For instance, [JavaCard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Card)'s JVM lacked garbage collection until v3.

Comment: +1 Excellent reference.  isGarbageCollectionSupported() and requestGarbageCollection() were actually introduced in JCVM 2.2.

Answer (score 3):

Garbage collection (if you ignore weak and soft references) is roughly a simulation of having infinite memory, at least for objects that are unreachable. If an object gets garbage collected in the woods and no code can reach it, did it make a sound?

In practice, JVMs without collectors would be few and far between because in practice memory is limited. About the only places I can think of where a JVM without a GC would be useful would be a research/learning JVM, or a JVM used only for very short-lived processes (where you know you'll destroy the entire JVM before it consumes too much memory).