# How to free object in android?

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java garbage collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5086800/java-garbage-collection)

I know that we have to free object in C, C++ after processing finish to get back the memory. However, I don't know how to free object in java and android. Is that enough for just assign `null` to the object?

Comment: it will be garbage collected when there are no active references to it.

Comment: An object will be reclaimed "at some pointer after" it is no longer strongly reachable.

Comment: good point: "at some pointer after". Rereading that was not clear in my comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**In Java it is un-necessary to free objects.**

Java has a built in Garbage Collector which runs when ever it needs to and clear out all resources that are no longer in use in order to free memory. A java developer may make a call to the java runtime to run the Garbage Collecter using `System.gc();` however this is just a suggestion to the runtime and may not always result in it being run.

In cases where you are using readers and images, be sure to call `.recycle()` and `.close()` where applicable.

Comment: don't call GC directly....

Comment: agree to above [why](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414105/why-is-it-a-bad-practice-to-call-system-gc/2414621#2414621)

Answer (score 4):

A simple java object especially (E.g. model objects) can be freed by garbage collector **IF** other objects has no reference to it.

If I were you, don't trust too much that garbage collector because there are some objects that you must free, one of them is the `Bitmap` objects

`Bitmap`s eat more RAM in your android app.

```
Bitmap b = createLargeBitmap();
Bitmap b2 = b;
```

If you remove all references to that object and let garbage collector kill it

```
b = null;
b2 = null;
```

you might get a memory leak or `OutOfMemory` error.

So you need to call `recycle()` to fully freed the bitmap.

```
b.recycle();
b = null;
b2 = null;
```

// Sorry for my wrong grammar :)

Answer (score 2):

In most cases, setting a var to null is enough. A better answer to answer your questions is how to leak the memory which details explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470651/creating-a-memory-leak-with-java) post .

Answer (score 1):

Memory deallocation is automatically done by Java garbage collector . You can't force garbage collector to free memory through your code.

Calling `System.gc()` doesnot guarantee garbage collector to **RUN and FREE** memory , final decision is taken by Java runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Android (which uses Java language) is a garbage-collected environment, meaning the virtual machine will automatically remove objects which no longer have any references.

Hence the question you should be asking is: how do you ensure your program does not use too much memory. This is normally achieved by ensuring you don't put too many objects in your in-memory data structure, persist your information into file system etc.