# JVM out of memory

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, external-sorting

I am implementing an external sort for a big file (~30GB), so after I have written the chunks in disk, I create `chunks` times `BufferedReader(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(outputPath), "UTF-8"), maxBufferSize)` being `maxBufferSize = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory() / chunks`. However I get a `OutOfMemory` Exception.

I guess that the garbage collector didn't have time enough to clean the memory (when I stop with the debugger it does not throw the exception), but in that case, why `Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()` is given that result?

Is it possible to explicitly call the garbage collection or the only option is sleep the process for some time?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we call the Garbage Collector explicitly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15632734/can-we-call-the-garbage-collector-explicitly)

Comment: Note also that freeMemory() tells you the total amount of free space on the heap, but there is no guarantee that there is a single contiguous block that large (in fact, that will usually not be the case).

Comment: It would be important to konw what kind of `OutOfMemoryError` you get - without knowing that we might send you off in the completely wrong direction. Also some (relevant) code would be nice....

Comment: why are you using such large buffers in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to explicitly call the garbage collection

Yes it is possible.  But it won't do any good.

The JVM will only throw an OOME after performing a full GC.  Calling `System.gc()` explicitly will (most likely) just waste CPU time.

---

Actually, I think your real problem is here:

> I create `chunks` times `BufferedReader(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(outputPath), "UTF-8"), maxBufferSize)` being `maxBufferSize = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory() / chunks`.

When you consider the various object overheads, `(maxBufferSize + overheads) * chunks` is probably a bit greater than the amount of free memory.

In general, it is a bad idea to run with a Java heap close to full.  Even if you don't run out of space entirely, you can find that running close to full will trigger many (too many) garbage collections.

In this case, you don't really get a lot of benefit from having really large I/O buffers.  Buffers in the range of 8KB to 64KB should be fine ... is my gut feeling.  See also Peter Lawrey's comment!

Comment: Buffers greater than 32 KB can be marginally slower. I suspect this is due to the size of the L1 cpu cache, but I have found it varies as to what is the optimal size.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `System.gc()`, but its not the most useful. You could try giving the program more memory.